# How to row reduce this 3x3 matrix with eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, initial-value-problems

[image]

I was able to go from the 1st to the 2nd one by adding the 1st row to the 3rd row and getting a 0 in the (3rd row, 2nd coloumn) position but I have no clue as to how to get to the third matrix in the image.

Thank you!

Comment: I think they subtracted 1st column from 3rd column. But I don't think any row operations will help you.

Comment: Ohhh, thank you! But they got from the 1st matrix to the 2nd matrix using row operation though right?

Comment: Yes, they added rows as you said

Comment: Thank you @Paul !